# Making last child of a table the same color as the table element above it

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table and in the css I'm using nth-child to make the background colors different:

```
.className tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}

.className tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

The table is created dynamically so there is no way to know how many rows there will be.

The design needs the last child of the table to match the background color of the child above it.

This is being built in TWIG.

Comment: Have you tried tr:last-child { background:#somecolor; }  Or if it has to be odd/even matching then would you like to see that jquery would tell you if it should be odd or even, the last-child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test both for last child and for odd or even.

```
tr:last-child:nth-child(odd) td{
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
tr:last-child:nth-child(even) td{
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Been traveling for work and just getting back to this but this was the perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to `inherit` a property value outside the scope of a parent-child scenario (eg; *cascading* style sheets). However if you're up for some javascript you can do it regardless whether it ends with odd or even. Example below.

```js
const tables = document.getElementsByClassName('className');

for (let i = 0, x = tables.length; i < x; i++) {
  const rowCount = tables[i].rows.length;
  
  tables[i].rows[rowCount-1].style.backgroundColor = 
  window.getComputedStyle(tables[i].rows[rowCount-2]).backgroundColor;

}
```

```css
.className tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

.className tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.examples table {
  margin: 3rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="examples">
  <table class="className">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="className">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="className">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah blah blah</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```